# called object type bool is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c++

I want to pass function `compare` as a parameter to function foo in the header file, and later then call it in the .cpp file

My A.hh looks like this:

```
class A {
public:

private:
    std::vector<int> vect;
    bool compare(const int &lhs, const int &rhs) { 
        vect.push_back(lhs);  // just a random function I came up with 
        return lhs <= rhs; 
    }
    std::vector<int> foo (std::vector<int>&v1, std::vector<int>&v2, bool(A::*func)(int,int)) {
       //Do something
       int i = 0;
       int j = 0;
       while (i<int(v1.size()) && j < int(v2.size())) {
            if (func(v1[i],v2[j])) <-- got issue here
                 //Do something    

      }
}
```

When I tried to call `func(v1[i],v2[j])`, I got error `called object type bool is not a function or function pointer`.

Also, how can I pass the function in the .cpp file? I tried the following but got error: 
`reference to non-static member function must be called`

```
std::vector<int> bar = foo(vector1,vector1,compare);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined the parameter `func` as a pointer to a member function which means it needs an object of the class `A` in order for it to be called. If you had an object named `obj` of type `A` the correct way to call it would be `(obj.*func)(v1[i], v2[j])`.

So to call the function on the current instance (or `this`) you would do call it like:

```c++
(this->*func)(v1[i], v2[j]);
```

Also, the parameter types in the function pointer have to match the parameter types of the `compare` method. `int` is not the same as `const int&` so you need to change those as well.

```c++
std::vector<int> foo(..., bool(A::*func)(const int&, const int&));
```

Comment: since inside the compare function I actually use another value defined in A private, sth like this ```std::vector<int>vect```. Therefore, when I change the function to static, I got this error ```invalid use of member vect in static member function```

Comment: @HaAnTran I see. Then all you need to do is change `func(v1[i], v2[j])` to `(this->*func)(v1[i], v2[j])`.

Comment: @HaAnTran If by "random" you mean "arbitrary", as in that's not what your real code does but you wanted to show that members are accessed, it seems like a strange example because a compare function should never have side effects like that (it should, in fact, be `const`!). But if that's all that's going on there then I guess we can ignore it

Comment: @0x499602D2 In the header file? Then I got the same error ```called object type bool is not a function or function pointer```

Comment: @HaAnTran Make sure you have the asterik. It should be `(this->*...`. Also, change `bool (A::*func)(int, int)` to `bool (A::*func)(const int&, const int&)`. The types in the parameters have to match with the types of the `compare` method.

Comment: Got it, I fixed that but in the cpp file. when I tried to pass ```std::vector<int> bar = foo(vector1,vector1,compare);``` , I got the same error ```reference to non-static member function must be called```

Comment: @HaAnTran Change `compare` to `&A::compare`.